# How to configure AWS Timestream SDK in React Native? (Error: Cant find variable Credential)

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sdk, amazon-timestream

I need to configure the RN SDK for AWS timestream but I keep getting an error:

> Cant find variable Credential.

```
import { TimestreamQueryClient, CreateDatabaseCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-timestream-query";

const client = new TimestreamQueryClient({
   region: "eu-west-1",
   credentials: new Credential('XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'), // fails here
   apiVersion: 'latest'
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?!

I was not able to find any documentation regarding the SDK configuration in RN.

Comment: @smac2020 here you go: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-timestream-query

Comment: @smac2020 how can I know which version i am using? I installed it via NPM which should install the latest version which is V3 I guess, right?

Comment: This is AWS SDK for JS V3

Comment: See my answer - I pointed you to the React setup instructions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using the **AWS SDK for JavaScript v3**. To successfully use this API, you need to setup you DEV environment - including your creds. All these details are discussed in the AWS JavaScript V3 DEV Guide. I recommend that you read topics in this guide - which includes setting up your creds.

[Setting up the SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-up.html)

As you want to work in React - this topic is very important for you to read - it has all the required instructions:

[Getting started in React Native](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-react-native.html)

This Guide is also referenced from the doc you pointed me too:

[image]

Comment: How do you actually add a unique auto increment ID. Sorry this is a different question but maybe you can give a quick answer

Comment: Have you seen examples here for this service -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.create-scheduledquery.html

Comment: thanks but thats not what I am doing, here is the link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058435/how-to-add-unique-id-when-inserting-data-in-aws-timestream . I would highly appreciate your help!