# How to add unique ID when inserting data in AWS Timestream?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-timestream

I am inserting some data in Timestream but I cant figure out how to have a unqiue ID.

```
 $date = new DateTime();
 $time = strval($date->getTimestamp() * 1000);

 $dimensions = [];
 $i = 0;
 while ($i < 1) {
    $expected_delivery = '2022-04-30 18:00:00';
    $created_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $completed_date = 'n/a';
    $completed = '0';
    $created_by = 'xxx xxxx';
    $sender_user_id = '1';
    $receiver_user_id = '2';
    $sender_company_id = '10';
    $receiver_company_id = '11';
    $remark = 'TEST REMARK TEST HERE';
    $receiver_address = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $dimensions[] = [
        'Dimensions' => [
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'expected_delivery', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $expected_delivery, // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'expected_delivery', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $expected_delivery, // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'created_date', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $created_date, // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'completed_date', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $completed_date, // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'completed', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => '0', // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'created_by', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $created_by, // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'sender_user_id', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $sender_user_id, // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'receiver_user_id', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $receiver_user_id, // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'sender_company_id', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $sender_company_id, // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'receiver_company_id', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $receiver_company_id, // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'remark', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $remark, // REQUIRED
            ],
            [
                'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
                'Name' => 'receiver_address', // REQUIRED
                'Value' => $receiver_address, // REQUIRED
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $i++;
 }

$query = [
    'CommonAttributes' => [
        'MeasureName' => 'transactions_cnt',
        'MeasureValue' => 'transactions_cnt',
        'MeasureValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
        'Time' => $time,
        'TimeUnit' => 'MILLISECONDS',
        'Version' => 1,
    ],
    'DatabaseName' => 'packaging_app',
    'Records' => $dimensions,
    'TableName' => 'transactions',
];
```

I was reading the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/data-modeling.html) where it states the unique IDs but it doesnt give any explanation how to actually do it in the code:

> If your application scenario requires you to store an unique
> identifier for every data point (e.g., a request ID, a transaction ID,
> or a correlation ID), modeling the ID attribute as a measure value
> will result in significantly better query latency. When modeling your
> data with multi-measure records, the ID appears in the same row in
> context with your other dimensions and time series data, so your
> queries can continue to use them effectively. For instance,
> considering a DevOps use case where if every data point emitted by a
> server has a unique request ID attribute, modeling the request ID as a
> measure value results in up to 4X lower query latency across different
> query types as opposed to modeling the unique request ID as a
> dimension.

Comment: As I've answered you on the other question, there's not an unique ID for Timestream. The dimensions together with the time, combined, are the unique ID. The document you've shown is about a unique ID for the service, for querying, and not for the table itself. The unique ID, in your case, would be a simple dimension called UniqueID.

Comment: @EduardoEliasSaléh thankyou, thats clear now. I am facing other issues, please check my reply to your comment in the other question